# Retrieving Coordinates from just Google Search API alone

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-search, google-search-api

is it possible to do that out without a Google API map? I searched everywhere and could not find any help for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. This Google example shows some of their tricks.
http://www.google.com/uds/samples/random/lead.html

Or, using excerpt from my code

```
var ls = new google.search.LocalSearch();
ls.setCenterPoint('New York');
ls.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, processResults, [ls]);
ls.execute('Barnes & Noble');
```

and callback

```
processResults: function(searcher) {
    if (searcher.results && searcher.results.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < searcher.results.length; i++) {
            var result = searcher.results[i];
            alert(result.lat + '  ' + result.lng);
        }
    }
}
```

General information, I'm sure you've already seen this:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/

**Braveyard** in his question also provided working example
[Disable Highlighting in Google API WebSearch Result Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384719/disable-highlighting-in-google-api-websearch-result-title)

Comment: thanks for the help :) i solved this using another method the other day already :D